# Trouble with certificates

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, certificates

I have a *Samsung Galaxy* tablet model *GT-P3110*.

I keep getting a message on my tablet each time I go to my Hotmail and Outlook email that there is a problem with the security certificate for these sites.

All the reading I'm doing so far would indicate that it might be a fault with my tablet.

I have already lost access to one email account, and while I cant be sure it was because of me ignoring the security certificate warnings, but I do not want it to happen again.

Can you please help. My date and time seem fine when I go into my settings, is there anywhere else I should be looking? Will I need to do a full factory reset – and if so how do I do this?